# Is there an event when the drawer's transition is completed on react-native-drawer

Tags: react-native

I'm using [react-native-drawer](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer) and want to fire a function right after the drawer is closed. Do we have the event or should I setTimeout to wait for the transition?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass the `onClose` prop. See [here](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/blob/7e2546a67da3c585f9d3e032fbd8d07e50819add/index.js#L50).